# perl: Plotting data from multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, plot

In my perl code, I have several arrays with the name 'a', 'b', 'c'.... 'e', 'f'. I am sending them as the argument while calling 'MyFunc'. There I want to plot any two arrays, for example, 'e' vs 'f'.

I tried in the following way (please look at the code), but I get a message that no data points are available in the line where *`my $gd = $graph->plot(\@e,\@f) or die $graph->error;`* command is being executed.

How to make it work?

```
MyFunc(
    'a' => [0, 1,2,3,4],
    'c' => [0, -1,2,-3,6],  
    'c' => [0, 2,4,2,5],
    'd' => [0, 1,2,3,4],
    'e' => [0, 9,2,1,7],
    'f' => [-2, 5,-1,1,7],
    'g' => [5, 1,8,-2,5],
);

sub MyFunc {

use GD::Graph::lines;
my $graph = GD::Graph::lines->new;

$graph->set( 
    x_label           => 'X Label',
    y_label           => 'Y label',
    title             => 'Some simple graph',
    y_max_value       => 8,
    y_tick_number     => 8,
    y_label_skip      => 2 
) or die $graph->error;

my $gd = $graph->plot(\@e,\@f) or die $graph->error;

open(IMG, '>file.gif') or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $gd->gif;
close IMG;


};
```

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`

Answer (score 2):

Passing an argument `'e' => [0,9,2,1,7]` to a subroutine does not automatically create a variable called `@e` inside the subroutine. Your subroutine does do not do any processing of arguments whatsoever. Consider something like this to do what you seem to want:

```
sub MyFunc {

    my %params = @_;
    ...
    my $gd = $graph->plot( [$params{"e"}, $params{"f"}] ) ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: This, but `plot` takes an ARRAY ref, so do `$graph->plot([$params{e}, $params{f}])`... or using hash slicing, `$graph->plot([@params{'e', 'f'}])`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Joshua.